# Simple way to replace and send data to a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I simply want to replace a fragment from the current fragment and add a new one.

I have studied that *Replace* is **Equal** to **removeCurrent + Add anotherFragment**

But in my situation i am facing a Problem. For the first two times it is running properly but after third attempt instead of replacing . it ads the fragment on me.

My approach fails now. Now i am asking that how can i send an id to other fragment like we do in Activities. I have a listView with a ReadMore button. I simply want to show the details in another fragment and want to send the index of a List.

I listen about some Interface but don't know how to implement . or there an easy way for communication. I tried doing it by passing it in Constructor . but it will give me an error . because

how to get currentFragment and hide it?
how to add onBackPressed to fragment.
how to send data between fragments The easy way.

i know how to hide or show a fragment

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().hide(frag[j]).commit();

getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().show(frag[0]).commit();
```

also know how to add or replace a fragment

```
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, frag[i])
                //.addToBackStack(null)
                .commit();

getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, frag[i])
            //.addToBackStack(null)
            .commit();
```

Tell me a better approach to send data and why my layout add instead of replacing.

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty easy to send data to fragment with constructor.

In your fragment class, add constructor like this:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment{
String id;

public MyFragment(String id)
this.id = id;
}
```

Then, when calling a fragment,you can easily send data like this :

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.r.id.container,new      MyFragment("123")).commit();
```

You can't override onBackPressed within fragment, you can only do that in activity

Comment: i know this way but it is not an appropriate becuause on Screen orientation all data will be lost and there are some other issues to. instead of this use bundle to send that because on Orientation change it will not change.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using EventBus for Activity/Fragment/Service or any other communication.

- There is a good one from Square: http://square.github.io/otto/
- Or this one (also very good): https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus

It makes it simplier and your code gets cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

You can set try set the variables in the fragment as `public static` then you can declare them before you instantiate your fragment to be shown.

in your `onDestroy` method of the fragment you can set the variables = null, so they dont take space in memory.

could be smth like this

```
MyFragment.theString = "A String";
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.r.id.container,new MyFragment()).commit();
```

And in your fragment

```
public static String theString;

...
public void onDestroy(){
super.onDestroy();
theString = null;
}
```